# How to mock a chained python function that returns different objects

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark, mocking, pytest

I am trying to mock function `write_tables_to_datalake_by_partition_datehour()` that has the following code.

```
tables_with_data[table].repartition("datehour_partition").write.format(
                "parquet"
            ).partitionBy("datehour_partition").mode("overwrite").save(
                cleansed_file_path + table
            )
```

`tables_with_data[table]` is of the type `pyspark.sql.DataFrame`. When looking at the chained functions, it stays a `DataFrame` until the `write` function returns a `DataFrameWriter`. The `DataFrameWriter` actually is able to use the rest of the functions.

I don't want to write data to our datalake. I want to mock it.

```
@mock.patch("module_name.io.DataFrame")
def test_write_tables_to_datalake_by_partition_datehour(mock_df) -> None:

    mock_df.return_value.repartition.return_value.write.format.return_value.partitionBy.return_value.mode.return_value.save.return_value = (
        "yes!"
    )
```

This does not work because `DataFrame` does not have the method `save`, this is only available in `DataFrameWriter`. But I cannot patch `DataFrameWriter` because I do not import it in my module, only `DataFrame` is.

I also tried

```
    with mock.patch.object(DataFrameWriter, "save") as mock1:
        mock1.return_value.format.partitionBy.mode.save.return_value = "test"

        result = write_tables_to_datalake_by_partition_datehour(
            tablenames,
            dataframes_cleansed,
            cleansed_file_path,
            dataframes_cleansed,
            quarantine_file_path,
        )
```

This also does not work. How can I mock it the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by importing the `DataFrameWriter` in my module. Then I mock the `save` return value and now it doesn't write to our datalake. Very simple solution.

```
@mock.patch("mymodule.io.DataFrameWriter.save", return_value="1")
def test_write_tables_to_datalake_by_partition_datehour(mock_dfw) -> None:
   # implementation
```

In my module I added this at the top so that my `mock.patch` can find the actual class

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameWriter
```

Even though it's an unused import, the mock needs it.